# Angular 2 onload event for a native DOM element

Tags: javascript, html, angular

My ultimate goal is to make a textarea element autofocus on creating. I have just thought of a solution to call `e.target.focus()` on event `onload`. Something like:

```
<textarea rows="8" col="60" (load)='handleLoad($event)'>
```

and then:

```
handleLoad(e){
  e.target.focus();
}
```

The problem is angular does not recognize `load` event.

PS: I tried `autofocus` once but it seems not working.

Comment: there is no such event for textarea, but you can use ng-include's onload if the same is exist in angular2

Comment: I was looking for the same thing but no luck.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You should be able to do it in ngAfterViewInit hook:

```
import { ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core'

// ...

export class Component implements AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('textarea') textarea: ElementRef

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.textarea.nativeElement.focus()
  }
}
```

Where in template you need to set template variable:

```
<textarea #textarea rows="8" col="60"></textarea>
```

Comment: The hook you should really use, if you're going to take this route, is `ngAfterViewInit()`. `ngOnInit()` is called after the class is instantiated, but there is no guarantee the view will be rendered already (and thus, there may be no `nativeElement` to focus). `ngAfterViewInit()` is called after the DOM is rendered. See [Angular's lifecycle hooks docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html).

Comment: @jessepinho You are right, I was planning to edit question too after I'm done with sandwitch. Thank you!

Comment: Take your time @dfsq. It's important to eat.

Comment: 'AfterViewInit' only fires once, and way before my element exists in the DOM. -- What event should I handle for when my specific element is displayed for the first time?

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 I have the same question. My 'AfterViewInit' is firing before I see data on UI for my component since I have some child components as well. Did you find the answer for your question?

Answer (score 9):

Try [the HTML5 `autofocus` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-autofocus):

```
<textarea rows="8" col="60" autofocus>
```

Always better (and a lot simpler!) to use the native DOM API if possible than to do it in JavaScript :)

EDIT: The above is incorrect. See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38409640/angular-2-onload-event-for-a-native-dom-element/38410018#comment64228538_38410018) below.

Comment: I would also say that it should be done like this. However, the problem is that it just doesn't work in most cases.

Comment: @dfsq What do you mean "in most cases"? [Looks like](http://caniuse.com/#search=autofocus) it's pretty well-supported.

Comment: I mean, it works well when HTML is rendered on page load. It doesn't work reliably when HTML is rendered asynchronously, like usually in SAP's. Check this test I was making: http://plnkr.co/edit/rpNKQRYJh3DuPafaVzqz?p=preview

Comment: @dfsq Works fine for me in Safari + Chrome. Tried in Firefox but there was a JS error in the console that prevented the app from starting.

Comment: Like I mentioned in my question, in my particular case, this doesn't work. What @dfsq said is true.

Comment: You see, I doesn't work for me in Chrome (Mac). Try in console: `document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', '<input autofocus>')`. Does it also work on your machine?

Comment: @PoBéo Would be good to see your code in Plunkr/JSFiddle to reproduce.

Comment: @dfsq Hmmm nope... But the Plunk did. Weird... Not sure what the difference is.

Comment: I stand [corrected](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#autofocusing-a-form-control:-the-autofocus-attribute:the-dialog-element): "The autofocus content attribute allows the author to indicate that a control is to be focused **as soon as the page is loaded or as soon as the dialog within which it finds itself is shown**, allowing the user to just start typing without having to manually focus the main control."

Answer (score 0):

#### 1) Custom `*ref` directive

Copy `ref.directive.ts` from project [RefFunc](https://github.com/M90K7/samples/tree/main/Angular/RefFunc) then add to `NgModule`

use `*ref` directive on element. call call-back function when element is created.

**sample:**

```html
<p *ref="changeStyle">Sample 1 :)</p>
```

```
 changeStyle(el: ElementRef) {
    (el.nativeElement as HTMLElement).style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(242, 119, 119)';
  }
```

---

#### 2) Tricky: use *ngIf directive (complex example).

```html
<!-- this template just for example. -->
<div *ngFor="let tab of page.tabs; let index=index">
    <input #tabCheckboxEle
       id="{{ 'checkbox_' + index }}"
       type="checkbox"
    />
    <label *ngIf="{_: onStateCheckbox(tab, tabCheckboxEle)}"
        for="{{ 'checkbox_' + index }}">{{ tab.title }}</label>
</div>
```

**`*ngIf` directive create truthy object properties then call function property.**

I'm use `*ngIf` on label element for need input reference.