# How to call a function when element is loaded at Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to call a function with an argument when an element is loaded.
Just like nginit in angualrjs. Can we do it in Angular 4 and above?

```html
    <div *ngFor="let item of questionnaireList"  
       (onload)="doSomething(item.id)" >
    </div>
```

My Typescript function:

```js
    doSomething(id) {
        console.log(id);
    }
```

Comment: use ngAfterViewInit

Comment: just elaborate the example i have to call a function and also pass argument @SandipPatel

Comment: arguments are input parameter OR component itself?

Comment: please can you explain with example @SandipPatel

Comment: use *ref directive https://stackoverflow.com/a/72378317/1279118

Answer (score 21):

You need to write a directive

```
import {Directive, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[ngInit]'
})
export class NgInitDirective {

  @Input() isLast: boolean;

  @Output('ngInit') initEvent: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  ngOnInit() {
    if (this.isLast) {
      setTimeout(() => this.initEvent.emit(), 10);
    }
  }
}
```

Using in html

```
<div *ngFor="let quetionnaireData of questionnairelist ; let $last = last" [isLast]='$last'
   (ngInit)="doSomething('Hello')"></div>
```

Also you declare your directive in app.module

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ..
    NgInitDirective 
  ],
  ......
})
```

Comment: Error  Can't bind to 'isLast' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. @Dakota

Comment: Did you add directive into declaration in module ?

Comment: sorry but i am noob in anguilar i am declaring the directive in the app.module.ts it is not getting

Comment: because there is two directive nginit and homecomponent  

so it is showing 
Unexpected value 'HomeComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule'

Comment: Can you add a piece of code on your post which related to your error ex app.module,..

Comment: Uncaught Error: Unexpected value 'HomeComponent' declared by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @Pipe/@Directive/@Component annotation.

Comment: better u should show code of HomComponent , Hard to give you solution if only read your errror

Comment: i have two directives 
export class nginitdirective { } ,
export class homecomponent { }  .

due to which there was declaration error

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46549876/please-add-a-pipe-directive-component-annotation-error . You can check your error in this question

Answer (score 6):

Use ngOnInit() and the @Input directive.
For example, in your child component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-component',
  template: `
  <h3>My id is: {{itemId}}</h3>
  `
})


export class MyComponent implements OnInit
{
  @Input() itemId: string;

  //other code emitted for clarity

  public ngOnInit(): void
  {
    // Now you can access to the itemId field e do what you need
    console.log(this.itemId);     
  }
}
```

In your parent component

```
<div *ngFor="let item of questionnairelist">
    <my-component itemId='{{item.Id}}'></my-component>
</div>
```

Comment: i don't have any child parent relationship 



 i just have single component

Comment: Not useful when you need the component to be fully loaded before doing any other thing.

Answer (score 5):

Your Function:

```
ExecuteMyFunction(value:any):void{
    console.log(value);
}
```

If you wants to pass parameter which declared in component itself and set from component then try as below:

```
notificationMessage:string='';
@Input() message:string;

ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.ExecuteMyFunction(this.notificationMessage);
}
```

If you set variable as Input parameter and set from other component then try as below: `ngOnChanges` will fire every time when your `Input` variable value is changed.

```
import { Component, OnChanges, Input } from '@angular/core';
ngOnChanges(changes: any) {
    if (changes.message != null && changes.message.currentValue != null) {
        this.ExecuteMyFunction(this.message);
    }        
}
```

Comment: <div *ngFor="let quetionnaireData of questionnairelist"  (onload)="dosomething('hello')" ></div>

call function dosomething

dosomething(h){  console.log(h);}

Comment: why you need onload event? ngAfterViewInit will call when view load

Comment: i want id from the item.id to be passeed as argument when the function  gets called

Comment: (onload) is AngularJS

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
   <div *ngIf="doSomething(item.id)"></div>
</ng-container>
```

TS:

```
doSomething(value){
  //logic
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32238228)

Comment: if condition call function infinite times

Answer (score -2):

```
import { Router,NavigationEnd } from '@angular/router';


constructor( private router: Router ) {
 this.router.events.subscribe((e) => {
   if (e instanceof NavigationEnd) {
       // Function you want to call here
   }
 });
}
```